# PL/SQL procedure with IN , OUT parameters

Tags: plsql

Table schema

```
jobs(v_id, v_name, v_salary)
```

I want to display the `v_name` and `v_salary` where `id` is passed in `IN` parameter

```
create or replace procedure jobs_select(
    id      IN  jobs.v_id%TYPE,
    position    OUT jobs.v_position%TYPE,
    salary  OUT jobs.v_salary%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
    select v_position into position, v_salary 

into salary  from jobs where v_id = id;

    dbms_output.put_line('Position: ' || position 

|| ' Salary: ' || salary);
END;
/
```

Gives error cannot find `'FROM'` where expected

Comment: You have a second `into` in your `select` statement.

Answer (score 2):

There was mistake in select statement, which is edited now, check the following:

```
    create or replace procedure jobs_select(
        id      IN  jobs.v_id%TYPE,
        position    OUT jobs.v_position%TYPE,
        salary  OUT jobs.v_salary%TYPE
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
        select v_position, v_salary into
             position, salary
            from jobs where v_id = id;

        dbms_output.put_line('Position: ' || position 

    || ' Salary: ' || salary);
    END;
    /

    -- And executed it like this:

    set serveroutput on;
    Declare
    v_id Number := 9999;
    v_name varchar2(100);
    v_salary number;
    Begin
    jobs_select(v_id, v_name, v_salary);
    end;
/
```